# Fade out parent DIV - but not the children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this HTML code :

```
<div id="espacePub">        

    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
            <li>Link 4</li>
            <li>Link 5</li>
            <li>Link 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- End Div menu -->

</div><!-- End Div espacePub -->
```

I want to select the div #espacePub but not the div #menu to fade out, change background and then fade in. With documentation found on http://api.jquery.com/not/, I tried this :

```
var imgs = [            
'img/pub.jpg',
'img/pub2.jpg',
'img/pub3.jpg'];
var cnt = imgs.length;

$(function() {
    setInterval(Slider, 2000);
});

function Slider() {
    $('#espacePub').not(document.getElementById('menu')).fadeOut("slow", function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url("'+imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]+'")').fadeIn("slow");
});
}
```

My problem is that the entire #espacePub is fading, including #menu but I don't want #menu fading... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As long as `menu` is inside of `espacePub`, it will fade as well. `fadeOut` takes the entire contents of whatever it matches. You need to take it out of the `espacePub` div.

Comment: by the way, you can use `#menu` instead of `document.getElementById('menu')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the `#escapePub` `position: relative;`
Create a div `#slider` inside the `#escapePub` with `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;` and apply jquery to it.

```
$('#espacePub #slider').fadeOut("slow",
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("'+imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]+'")')
               .fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

Comment: I think you mean position: relative, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave the nested element with the opacity 100% when you change it's parent opacity. Probably you need get `#menu` div from the `#espacePub` and position it absolute over `#espacePub`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the espacePub div contains the menu div so when you fade it everything inside has to be hidden. To do what you want they will need to be separate elements.

Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beckje01/TAthQ/) showing you an example. Note I changed the images to colors so it was easier to set up on jsFiddle.