# How do you only fade a specific element in a parents children with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

How would you make it so the P inside each .nav didn't fade?

http://jsfiddle.net/vbqfD/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', .5);
});

$('.nav').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

});

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529371/fade-out-parent-div-but-not-the-children

Answer (score 1):

You are setting opacity of the element to 0.5, this affects the children too, I'd suggest:

```
.nav {
    ... 
    background: rgba(130, 202, 255, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

.nav:hover {
    background-color: rgba(130, 202, 255, 0.5);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NwRXs/3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Isn't there a way to only affect what you select and not the children in JQuery?

Comment: What you are modifying is opacity, this is not related to jQuery, this is how browsers handle the opacity,  what's wrong with using css?

Comment: I was just curious if it was possible, that's all. I'm also still new to HTML/CSS and especially JavaScript. I see how using CSS is a lot more straightforward. I didn't realize you could do that.